# Keep getting "Empty oauth2_access_token" error

Tags: linkedin-api

We have a problem when connecting to your REST-api. We keep getting "errorCode": 0, "message": "Empty oauth2_access_token"} in out log for a specific production site. The thing is that we are using the exact same configuration and access tokens on our test site and we have never encountered the problem there. I would like help with finding out exactly what the problem is.

Best regards,
Rikard

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Copy-paste error when saving secret key. /facepalm